# Do we have alternative to Java 9 CompletableFuture methods to handle timeouts?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, completable-future

I want a way to handle timeouts(custom value) for completable futures where we can assign a default value to the future object if there is a timeout. I know there are a couple of methods to handle it in Java 9 and above.

But is there any alternative to Java 9 CompletableFuture methods similar to

```
public CompletableFuture<T> completeOnTimeout(T value, long timeout,                                                   TimeUnit unit)
OR
public CompletableFuture<T> orTimeout(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
```

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can simulate them using the inherited [Future.get(long, TimeUnit)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) method.

Comment: @VGR the `get` method forces the caller to *wait* up to the specified time for the completion. In contrast, the methods mentioned in the question will *complete the future* with the alternative result (value or `TimeoutException`) after the elapsed time, *without actually waiting*. In other words, these methods do entirely different things.

Comment: @Holger Correct.  It’s not a drop-in replacement, but you can use it to write your own equivalent of the Java 9+ timeout methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no magic in the methods `completeOnTimeout` and `orTimeout`. When you have something like

```java
CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toNanos(1));
    return "ordinary value";
});
cf.completeOnTimeout("timeout value", 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

cf.thenAccept(System.out::println).join();
```

you can do the same in Java 8 with

```java
static final ScheduledExecutorService TIMEOUT_SCHEDULER
                                      = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(0);
```

```java
CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toNanos(1));
    return "ordinary value";
});
TIMEOUT_SCHEDULER.schedule(()->cf.complete("timeout value"), 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

cf.thenAccept(System.out::println).join();
```

To be closer to what Java 9’s `CompletableFuture` does internally, e.g. use daemon threads, keep at least one thread alive, and having cleanup for cases where the future is completed ordinarily earlier than the timeout, you may use a helper class like

```java
public final class TimeoutSupport {
    private static final ScheduledExecutorService TIMEOUT_SCHEDULER;
    static {
        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor e = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1, r -> {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            return t;
        });
        e.setRemoveOnCancelPolicy(true);
        TIMEOUT_SCHEDULER = e;
    }

    public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> orTimeout(
        CompletableFuture<T> cf, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {
        return withTimeout(cf,
            ()->cf.completeExceptionally(new TimeoutException()), timeout, unit);
    }

    public static <T> CompletableFuture<T> completeOnTimeout(
        CompletableFuture<T> cf, T value, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {

        return withTimeout(cf, () -> cf.complete(value), timeout, unit);
    }

    private static <T> CompletableFuture<T> withTimeout(
        CompletableFuture<T> cf, Runnable action, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {

        Future<?> f = TIMEOUT_SCHEDULER.schedule(action, timeout, unit);
        cf.whenComplete((o, t) -> f.cancel(false));
        return cf;
    }

    private TimeoutSupport() {}
}
```

to be used like

```java
CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(20));
    return "ordinary value";
});
TimeoutSupport.completeOnTimeout(cf, "timeout value", 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

cf.thenAccept(System.out::println).join();
```

or in a fluent style

```java
TimeoutSupport.completeOnTimeout(
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(20));
        return "ordinary value";
    }), "timeout value", 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.thenAccept(System.out::println).join();
```

though not as neat as just chaining, like with Java 9’s methods.

The `orTimeout` method works similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ExecutorService` and then `Future#get(long, TimeUnit)`. They are available as of Java 1.5 (the 5th version) if I am not mistaken.

```java
final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
final Future<String> future = executorService.submit(() -> {
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
    return "Success";
});

try {
    final String result = future.get(1500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
    System.out.println("Error");
} finally {
    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Though this does not complete the future with an alternative value.